# Checking upgrade process went ok

Tags: upgrade

So I have been updating from 16.04 and ended up somehow on 18.04. Question 1: Will the following update the Distribution version as well?

`apt update -y && apt full-upgrade -y && apt autoremove -y`

Because I ran `do-release-upgrade` and it said - please download all available updates, I ran the above line and next thing its said its done a release upgrade.

Oddly when I ran the command on a separate server it never touched the release upgrade. So is Ubuntu clever enough to know that I've tried to do a a `do-release-upgrade`, done my update so now complete or am I just missing something obvious?

`lsb_release -a` now reports 20.04 LTS but wanted to make sure it definitely was.

Comment: `apt full-upgrade` will upgrade your system fully, but will **not** change your release unless you've polluted sources with those intended for later releases.  The most it can do is if you were using 16.04.6 *for example*, you'll find yourself upgraded to the latest 16.04.7.

Comment: If a `do-release-upgrade` fails, it should restore your system including your sources. Myself, I always check them anyway to ensure there is no pollution (`do-release-upgrade` has to upgrade sources to later version for the upgrade, but I check to ensure they got returned as expected, as if they're wrong, `apt full-upgrade` will do something unintended because of the polluted sources).

Comment: I wondering if my lists got polluted - that would make sense

Comment: If so - does that mean the version is still correct? I.e. it is genuinely 20.04?

Comment: Advice: It's unwise to chain apt commands together and to use -y when you don't know what the result will be. The answers to all of these questions are in the output of those commands. Get into the habit of reviewing the proposed changes before agreeing. This site is soaked in the tears of folks who learned the hard way. You were fortunate.

Comment: I agree with user535733 (esp. '-y').  A `sudo apt update` will give the quick & pretty good clue as to your status (current status and what will occur before subsequent commands; why the output is shown!).  An upgrade from 16.04 LTS will only go to 16.10 (next release but impossible as it's now EOL) or to 18.04 (next LTS release) so a bump to 20.04 is impossible as you describe unless someone with `sudo` rights had polluted your sources, and it wasn't by the `do-release-upgrade` command.